# Loop is doesn't complete properly in C#

Tags: c#, loops, asp.net-mvc-4, while-loop

I have an ASP.NET MVC project. After the button click event, I call a method. But this method doesn't work properly. It's completing must take at least 2 minutes, but it is completing in 10 seconds.

Here's my code:

```
public ActionResult TavMethod()
{
        ResetAttributes();
        ArdistirmaSayisi = 200;
        Alfa = 0.99;
        Sicaklik = 50;

        while (this.Sicaklik>1)
        {
            while (ArdistirmaSayisi > 0)
            {
                ArdistirmaSayisi--;
            }

            this.Sicaklik = this.Sicaklik * Alfa;
        }

        return View(Tuple.Create(MakinaIslerEniyi, WorkProcess.CmakeMS));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do here? If you want to insert a delay you have better options than this code.

Comment: Why do you think this should take 2 minutes? BTW: The inner loop executes just once.

Comment: @Steve in actually this code is about, Simulated Annealing algorithm. I dont wanna insert delay. Just, ı want to work properly ı mean every descending  Sicaklik, inner loop run 200 time.. But it doesnt..

Comment: @PMF this code  must take at least 2 minutes. But it has complated in 10 second.. it doesnt work properly..

Comment: @Nisanur after the first loop the variable _ArdistirmaSayisi_ reaches the value of 0. You never reset this variable to its initial value of 200. So every successive loop, the inner loop is never executed

Comment: And what's the point of `while (ArdistirmaSayisi > 0) {ArdistirmaSayisi--;}`? Just to waste some CPU?

Comment: @Steve You are right, but   for (int iterasyon = 0; iterasyon < ArdistirmaSayisi; iterasyon++)  with change my code. this state continue..  again, loops doesnt work properly

Comment: @Evk Loop's inside full of calculating codes, so, I removed..

Comment: @Nisanur now you are talking about code that is not shown above. Really, without a [MCVE], is difficult to help you.

Comment: @Steve you are right.. Im sorry

Comment: Why on Earth would you want to block a thread on  your server for 2 minutes?

Comment: It does not work properly?  How do you know it does not work properly?  VTC

Comment: @Steve thanks a lot.. I solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are very sure to pause for 2 minutes, why not use something like `Thread.Sleep`

**Example** (pause 10 seconds)

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( 10000 );//10 seconds
//Other logic
return View(Tuple.Create(MakinaIslerEniyi, WorkProcess.CmakeMS));
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont wanna pause.. just ı know this code blocks take a long time. But it is fininshing in 10 seconds.. I solve my problem..